# change output to a file using DELPHI IDE

Tags: delphi

we can't redirect the output inside the DELPHI IDE for an command line application  to e.g. to a file.

We know how to do this using Pycharm IDE but did not find a solution using Delphi 
[image]

Is there any other solution with Delphi IDE existing ?

Delphi 10.3 RIO
Community Version used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not within the IDE, but from code it is possible.

In your console program, insert these lines at the top of the program:

```
AssignFile(Output,'MyOutputFile.txt');
Rewrite(Output);
```

This will redirect the [standard output handler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_Routines_and_Input-Output#Text_Files) to a text file.

Example that outputs the text into a file only in debug mode:

```
program TestFileOutput;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
  {$IFDEF debug}  // Output to text file only in debug mode
  AssignFile(Output,'MyOutputFile.txt');
  Rewrite(Output);
  {$ENDIF}
  WriteLn('Hello Delphi');
end.
```